# UnsupportedOperationException for ServletRequest.getServletContext()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm working on upgrading an existing app from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.1. This app is deployed as a WAR file in an existing Tomcat instance.

I've gotten past most of the migration hurdles, but now I'm seeing that, when Thymeleaf's Spring Security Dialect tries to check `sec:authorize-url` rules, I get an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
2019-08-13 15:31:22,836 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  - Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: public abstract javax.servlet.ServletContext javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getServletContext() is not supported
    at org.springframework.security.web.UnsupportedOperationExceptionInvocationHandler.invoke(FilterInvocation.java:235)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy386.getServletContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getServletContext(ServletRequestWrapper.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest$AbstractRequestMatcher.matches(EndpointRequest.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.security.servlet.ApplicationContextRequestMatcher.matches(ApplicationContextRequestMatcher.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.getAttributes(DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:95)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.java:103)
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.auth.AuthUtils$MvcAuthUtils.authorizeUsingUrlCheckMvc(AuthUtils.java:362)
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.auth.AuthUtils$MvcAuthUtils.access$300(AuthUtils.java:304)
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.auth.AuthUtils.authorizeUsingUrlCheck(AuthUtils.java:236)
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.processor.AuthorizeUrlAttrProcessor.isVisible(AuthorizeUrlAttrProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.java:61)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    ... 137 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.processor.AuthorizeUrlAttrProcessor' (template: "fragments/header" - line 41, col 37)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 113 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.processor.AuthorizeUrlAttrProcessor' (template: "fragments/header" - line 41, col 37)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 111 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/home.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter.doFilter(TogglzFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The Thymeleaf code at the exception point is just a `sec:authorize-url` attribute, like:

```html
<li sec:authorize-url="/foo">...</li>
```

I can't see any obvious reason why the ServletContext wouldn't be available. Any pointers on how to debug this further would be greatly appreciated.

This only happens after I've logged in, so I know that Thymeleaf and the Servlet stuff aren't fundamentally broken, as I see my custom login page. It seems like there must just be some "gotcha" with the Spring Security Dialect that I've missed, or maybe something weird with some other Filter somewhere?

---

**Update**

I've poked around in the debugger, and I see that this is occurring when `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest.AbstractRequestMatcher#matches` is invoked with a `org.springframework.security.web.DummyRequest`.

The stack at that point, approximately:

```
matches:138, EndpointRequest$AbstractRequestMatcher (org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet)
matches:57, ApplicationContextRequestMatcher (org.springframework.boot.security.servlet)
getAttributes:95, DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource (org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept)
isAllowed:103, DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator (org.springframework.security.web.access)
authorizeUsingUrlCheckMvc:362, AuthUtils$MvcAuthUtils (org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.auth)
access$300:304, AuthUtils$MvcAuthUtils (org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.auth)
authorizeUsingUrlCheck:236, AuthUtils (org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.auth)
isVisible:74, AuthorizeUrlAttrProcessor (org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.processor)
doProcess:61, AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor (org.thymeleaf.standard.processor)
doProcess:74, AbstractAttributeTagProcessor (org.thymeleaf.processor.element)
process:95, AbstractElementTagProcessor (org.thymeleaf.processor.element)
process:633, ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper (org.thymeleaf.util)
handleOpenElement:1314, ProcessorTemplateHandler (org.thymeleaf.engine)
beHandled:205, OpenElementTag (org.thymeleaf.engine)
process:282, Model (org.thymeleaf.engine)
handleOpenElement:1587, ProcessorTemplateHandler (org.thymeleaf.engine)
beHandled:205, OpenElementTag (org.thymeleaf.engine)
process:282, Model (org.thymeleaf.engine)
handleOpenElement:1587, ProcessorTemplateHandler (org.thymeleaf.engine)
beHandled:205, OpenElementTag (org.thymeleaf.engine)
process:282, Model (org.thymeleaf.engine)
process:290, Model (org.thymeleaf.engine)
process:78, GatheringModelProcessable (org.thymeleaf.engine)
handleCloseElement:1640, ProcessorTemplateHandler (org.thymeleaf.engine)
handleCloseElementEnd:388, TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler (org.thymeleaf.engine)
handleCloseElementEnd:322, InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler (org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup)
handleCloseElementEnd:220, OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler (org.thymeleaf.standard.inline)
handleCloseElementEnd:164, InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler (org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup)
handleCloseElementEnd:169, HtmlElement (org.attoparser)
handleCloseElementEnd:412, HtmlMarkupHandler (org.attoparser)
handleCloseElementEnd:473, MarkupEventProcessorHandler (org.attoparser)
parseCloseElement:201, ParsingElementMarkupUtil (org.attoparser)
parseBuffer:725, MarkupParser (org.attoparser)
parseDocument:301, MarkupParser (org.attoparser)
parse:257, MarkupParser (org.attoparser)
parse:230, AbstractMarkupTemplateParser (org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup)
parseStandalone:100, AbstractMarkupTemplateParser (org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup)
parseAndProcess:666, TemplateManager (org.thymeleaf.engine)
process:1098, TemplateEngine (org.thymeleaf)
process:1072, TemplateEngine (org.thymeleaf)
renderFragment:362, ThymeleafView (org.thymeleaf.spring5.view)
render:189, ThymeleafView (org.thymeleaf.spring5.view)
render:1371, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
processDispatchResult:1117, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doDispatch:1056, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doService:942, DispatcherServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
processRequest:1005, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
doGet:897, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
service:635, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
service:882, FrameworkServlet (org.springframework.web.servlet)
service:742, HttpServlet (javax.servlet.http)
internalDoFilter:231, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:52, WsFilter (org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:100, TogglzFilter (org.togglz.servlet)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:63, ResourceUrlEncodingFilter (org.springframework.web.servlet.resource)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilterInternal:262, AbstractRequestLoggingFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:118, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:200, SwitchUserFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilterInternal:88, HttpTraceFilter (org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet)
doFilter:118, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:320, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:200, SwitchUserFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
invoke:127, FilterSecurityInterceptor (org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept)
doFilter:91, FilterSecurityInterceptor (org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:119, ExceptionTranslationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.access)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:137, SessionManagementFilter (org.springframework.security.web.session)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:111, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:170, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (org.springframework.security.web.servletapi)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:63, RequestCacheAwareFilter (org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:158, BasicAuthenticationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www)
doFilter:118, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:200, AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:116, LogoutFilter (org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:74, HeaderWriterFilter (org.springframework.security.web.header)
doFilter:118, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:105, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (org.springframework.security.web.context)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:56, WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async)
doFilter:118, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:334, FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilterInternal:215, FilterChainProxy (org.springframework.security.web)
doFilter:178, FilterChainProxy (org.springframework.security.web)
invokeDelegate:357, DelegatingFilterProxy (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:270, DelegatingFilterProxy (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilterInternal:93, HiddenHttpMethodFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:118, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:128, ErrorPageFilter (org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support)
access$000:66, ErrorPageFilter (org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support)
doFilterInternal:103, ErrorPageFilter$1 (org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support)
doFilter:118, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:121, ErrorPageFilter (org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
filterAndRecordMetrics:114, WebMvcMetricsFilter (org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet)
doFilterInternal:104, WebMvcMetricsFilter (org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet)
doFilter:118, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilterInternal:200, CharacterEncodingFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
doFilter:118, OncePerRequestFilter (org.springframework.web.filter)
internalDoFilter:193, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
doFilter:166, ApplicationFilterChain (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:199, StandardWrapperValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:96, StandardContextValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:493, AuthenticatorBase (org.apache.catalina.authenticator)
invoke:137, StandardHostValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
invoke:81, ErrorReportValve (org.apache.catalina.valves)
invoke:660, AbstractAccessLogValve (org.apache.catalina.valves)
invoke:87, StandardEngineValve (org.apache.catalina.core)
service:343, CoyoteAdapter (org.apache.catalina.connector)
service:798, Http11Processor (org.apache.coyote.http11)
process:66, AbstractProcessorLight (org.apache.coyote)
process:808, AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler (org.apache.coyote)
doRun:1498, NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor (org.apache.tomcat.util.net)
run:49, SocketProcessorBase (org.apache.tomcat.util.net)
runWorker:1149, ThreadPoolExecutor (java.util.concurrent)
run:624, ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker (java.util.concurrent)
run:61, TaskThread$WrappingRunnable (org.apache.tomcat.util.threads)
run:748, Thread (java.lang)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found the change I made that broke this.

As part of migrating my security config, I made use of a version of the `EndpointRequest` code in the [Actuator Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#actuator-security) section of the Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide, specifically, I added this to my existing bunch of `antMatchers()`

```java
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
                // ...
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health"))
                    .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
                    .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MONITORING")
                // ...
```

That doesn't seem to play nice with the way that the Thymeleaf Spring Security Dialect interrogates Spring Security about things.

So, I'm not sure if this is a bug in Spring Security, Thymeleaf, or both, but at least I have a workaround...

Comment: I've reported this to Thymeleaf: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity/issues/66